# What does "part of a settlement" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Locke tends to get linked up with rebels...He is a part of the
>   settlement. (heard from an English professor)

He was talking about John Locke's life. How to understand "he is part of the settlement"? Does it mean that he participates in the process of reaching it, or that this settlement highly influences his life?

Comment: Can you provide more context? (Did the professor describe *rebels* or *settlement* further, for example? Or can you give a synopsis of what was said during '...'?) From the above I suspect a play on words, using *part of a settlement* to mean Locke was both a member in a *community* and an *agreement*.

Answer (score 1):

I think "settlement" was likely used in place of "establishment." The latter makes much more sense in opposition to "rebels," inasmuch as "countercultural" forces tend to take on "the establishment."